# how to (crud) insert select update delete on mysql 5.7 json column

Tags: mysql, json, crud

In order to record user mac_address and count mac_address to restirct user login's pc or notebook to control user available max for example (it's work) :

```
SELECT JSON_LENGTH(auth_list->'$.mac') FROM users WHERE username='admin'
```

So I try
Step:01 create table

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id',
  `username` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'username',
  `auth_list` json DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'mac address list',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Step:02

```
INSERT INTO users ( username,auth_list )
VALUES('admin','{"mac":["b0fc361479de"]}')
```

Step:03 (Command not error but not insert new value)

```
UPDATE users SET auth_list = JSON_INSERT(auth_list , '$.mac','c84wr8492eda') WHERE username='admin'
```

I hope 
after execute sql (Step02) command it will make auth_list column’s value result like

```
{"mac": "b0fc361479de"}
```

to

```
{"mac": ["b0fc361479de","c84wr8492eda"]}
```

By the way

1. Select sql command for json column ? could be example?
   If I want to check whether mac value exsists 'c84wr8492eda' (get count)
2. update sql command for json column (replace)? could be example?
   If I want to where mac value is 'c84wr8492eda' to be 'aaaabbbbcccc'
3. Delete sql command for json column ? Could be example?
   if I want to delete a item where mac value is 'c84wr8492eda'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

q1: Try something like:

```
MySQL [localhost+ ssl/test] SQL> select json_contains(auth_list,js
r8492eda'),'$.mac') from users;
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| json_contains(auth_list,json_quote('c84wr8492eda'),'$.mac') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                           1 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

q2: I think you want to use JSON_ARRAY_APPEND instead of JSON_INSERT in step 03.

q3: Do you want to delete the record entirely or just the entry in the array?  Please peruse https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html